# I want to save a username and password in shared preferences

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sharedpreferences

I am  Learning android development. I am making a registration and login app. my registration and login working properly. But I don't know how to save username and password in shared preference. and set a boolean value to check in slash screen to check login.
here my code.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final AppCompatActivity activity = LoginActivity.this;

    private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;

    private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutEmail;
    private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutPassword;

    private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextEmail;
    private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextPassword;

    private AppCompatButton appCompatButtonLogin;

    private AppCompatTextView textViewLinkRegister;

    private InputValidation inputValidation;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        initViews();
        initListeners();
        initObjects();
        animationDrawable=(AnimationDrawable)nestedScrollView.getBackground();
        animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(1000);
        animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(1000);
        animationDrawable.start();

        //saving data in shared priference
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("Login",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isLogin",true);
        editor.putString("user", String.valueOf(textInputEditTextEmail));
        editor.putString("pass", String.valueOf(textInputEditTextPassword));
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * This method is to initialize views
     */
    private void initViews() {

        nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);

        textInputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutEmail);
        textInputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutPassword);

        textInputEditTextEmail = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextEmail);
        textInputEditTextPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextPassword);

        appCompatButtonLogin = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.appCompatButtonLogin);

        textViewLinkRegister = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLinkRegister);

    }

    /**
     * This method is to initialize listeners
     */
    private void initListeners() {
        appCompatButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        textViewLinkRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * This method is to initialize objects to be used
     */
    private void initObjects() {
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
        inputValidation = new InputValidation(activity);

    }

    /**
     * This implemented method is to listen the click on view
     *
     * @param v
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.appCompatButtonLogin:
                verifyFromSQLite();
                break;
            case R.id.textViewLinkRegister:
                // Navigate to RegisterActivity
                Intent intentRegister = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentRegister);
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is to validate the input text fields and verify login credentials from SQLite
     */
    private void verifyFromSQLite() {
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextEmail(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
            return;
        }
        if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextPassword, textInputLayoutPassword, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
            return;
        }

        if (databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()
                , textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
            Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, HomePage.class);
            accountsIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
            emptyInputEditText();
            startActivity(accountsIntent);
            finish();
        } else {
            // Snack Bar to show success message that record is wrong
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.error_valid_email_password),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is to empty all input edit text
     */
    private void emptyInputEditText() {
        textInputEditTextEmail.setText(null);
        textInputEditTextPassword.setText(null);
    }
}
```

This is my slash screen code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static  int slash_screen_time_out=4000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },slash_screen_time_out);
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this problem. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please have a look at this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233035/best-option-to-store-username-and-password-in-android-app)

Comment: What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: just a piece of advice, you shouldn't be storing the password on the device, you should use some authtoken or cookies for authentication.

Comment: I want like remember password if user login in once and after uses user closed the app. but when user open the app again then directly go on the Home page.

Comment: Which is it? `I want to save a username and password in shared preferences .` or `I am a using a Database sqlite`? Are you using shared prefs or an SQL database?

Comment: I am using SQLite database. But I want to store username and password in shared preference. @Zoe

Answer (score 1):

Save data in shared preferences by this way:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Login", 0);
settings.edit().putString("user", username).apply();
...
```

And check data on splash screen

```
String username = settings.getString("user", "");
if (username.isEmpty()){
   //.. data not saved
} else { 
 //.. data saved
}
```